# How do I set a URL that includes an ampersand with Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have something like:

```
Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
final Context ctx = new Context(defaultLocale);
String url = getHost() + "/page?someId=" + some.getId() + "&someParam=" + Boolean.TRUE;
ctx.setVariable("url", url);

final String htmlContent = templateEngine.process("theHtmlPage", ctx);
```

But when I look at the resulting HTML to print `url`, it shows `&amp` instead of `&` in the URL.

Any suggestions?

I tried using backticks to escape the ampersand in the Java code, but it just printed those too.  Looked around on SO, but didn't find much that was relevant. Also tried `&#038;`

Update: Ok, this won't break the link, but Spring doesn't seem to resolve the parameter "someParam" as true without it.

Rendering tag:

```
<span th:utext="${url}"></span>
```

Output:

```
<span>http://localhost:8080/page?someId=1&amp;someParam=true</span>
```

Comment: This won't break the link and is the correct behavior in HTML. Check the other question.

Comment: Updated.  I understand that the resulting HTML must include the &amp; as stated in the related question, but that doesn't help me generate the correct URL from the Java class.  I'm trying to understand how people solve this, even with a work-around.

Comment: You probably need to be using `utext` instead of `text` in your template. Show the rendering tag.

Comment: @chrylis, great thought, but no

Comment: Thymeleaf version? There were fixes in a very recent minor for this stuff.

Comment: 2.1.3.RELEASE.  I can try 2.1.4 and see whether that helps.

Comment: @chrylis can you please post an answer about the Thymeleaf version so that I may accept it?  It works in 2.1.4.RELEASE!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This wasn't a duplicate; it was an issue with a Thymeleaf bug where escapes were handled an incorrect number of times, and the latest release version fixes the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf [had a recent issue with encoding escapes](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/255), which has been fixed in 2.1.4.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use the dedicated [thymeleaf link url syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls).

If you want to construct and url with two parameters and set it to an `href` attribute you can do like this:

```
<a th:href="@{page(param1 = ${param1}, param2 = ${param2})}">link</a>
```

The generated html will be:

```
<a href="page?param1=val1&amp;param2=val2">link</a>
```

and the browser will request:

```
page?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

=== EDIT ===

To answer the downvote of dopatraman, I've just tested (again) my answer and it works well.

In my answer, the ampersand used as a parameters separator is automatically added by thymeleaf. And this added ampersand is **html entity encoded, by thymeleaf, to be stored in the html**.

If you have another ampersand inside param1 or param2, this ampersand should be **html entity encoded inside the thymeleaf template**. But it will **appear percent encoded in the generated html**.

### Example (tested with thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE):

`param1` has value `abc` and `param2` has value `12&3`

Inside the thymeleaf template all ampersand must be encoded as html entity and we have:

```
<a th:href="@{page(param1 = ${'abc'}, param2 =${'12&amp;3'})}">link</a>
```

In the generated html, the ampersand used as a parameter separator is encoded as an html entity and the ampersand in the param2 value is percent-encoded by thymeleaf:

```
<a href="page?param1=abc&amp;param2=12%263">link</a>
```

When you click on the link, the browser will decode the html entity encoding but not the percent-encoding, and the url in the adress bar will be:

```
<a href="page?param1=abc&amp;param2=12%263">link</a>
```

Checking with wireshark, we obtain from the HTTP request:

```
GET /page?param1=abc&param2=12%263
```

Comment: this is incorrect. the browser request will keep the escaped token, making the query string argument `amp;param2` instead of `param2`

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this kind of problems instead of '&' symbol you can use UTF code for that symbol, e.g in case of UTF-8 use '\u0026'.