# Thymeleaf rendering error when using ampersand in script tag

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web, thymeleaf

I want to add google map javascript to a Thymeleaf template, like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places
```

It throws the exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 209; columnNumber: 93; The reference to entity "key" must end with the ';' delimiter
```

I tried to change `&` to `&amp;` but nothing changed.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Because Thymeleaf template is XML, you should use `&amp;` instead of `&` in attribute values.

Comment: You have to encode & into &amp;.Because &amp; is an escaped sequence of & and the XML would find it as a literal.

Answer (score 6):

Thymeleaf uses XML parser, and the character `&` is considered a special character in XML. You have to replace `&` with its XML equvilant `&amp;`.Your URL will be:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=places
```

In thymeleaf 3, it won't be a problem since they wrote a new parser for thymeleaf.

Comment: Hi @Aboodz , I tried that but it doesnt work for me... thanks for your answer

Comment: @Aboodz , in this case Spring returns 400. Required parameter 'someParam' is not present.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in Thymeleaf but it was fixed since 2.1.4.

Look at this [issue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/255).
(The trouble described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464100/how-do-i-set-a-url-that-includes-an-ampersand-with-thymeleaf)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @sanluck !
Actually I'm using 2.1.4 version,but issue still exists for me..

Comment: Like this :
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=xxx&libraries=places" />

Is there anything wrong ?

Comment: I think it must looks like that : `<script type="text\javascript" th:src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js(v=3.exp,key=xxx,libraries=places)">`

Comment: Please [see this file](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) P.S. I posted incorrect URL, it must be `<script type="text\javascript" th:src="@{https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js(v=3.exp,key=xxx,libraries=places‌​)}">`

Comment: it throws an exception like this `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "@{https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js(v=3.exp,key=xxx,libraries=plac‌​es‌​)}"`

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

1) Don't use the `th:src` at all.

2) Since the URL is absolute, you can add it server-side using a static method:

```
<script th:src="${@urlService.getMapsUrl()}">...</script>
```

3) Use a [rewrite filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725943/how-to-get-absolute-url-as-href-src-value-using-thymeleaf-and-urlrewritefilter).

Not sure whether the issue is corrected in Thymeleaf 3, but it could be worth upgrading quickly and taking a look.