# How to get absolute url as href/src value using Thymeleaf and Urlrewritefilter

Tags: url-rewriting, spring-boot, thymeleaf, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) templating engine with Spring boot for developing my web application. For rewriting url, I'm using [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) library.

My problem is that I couldn't able to rewrite url to a absolute url. For example, if script src value is configured in html like below

```
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery.js}"></script>
```

and rules defined in urlrewrite.xml as

```
<urlrewrite>
        <outbound-rule>
            <from>/js/jquery.js</from>
            <to>https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.js</to>
        </outbound-rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

The expected output is

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.js"></script>
```

But it is generating as

```
<script src="/myapphttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.js"></script>
```

where **/myapp** is context root. How to get rid of context root and get only absolute url which I configured.

Comment: The problem is first THymeleaf replaces the src tag and makes it `/myapp/js/query.js` then you tell the `UrlRewriteFilter` to replace the `/js/jquery.js` part with a full URL and this is exactly what it does. Either don't use `th:src` or include `/webapp` in your rewrite rule, or just specify the full CDN url instead of using a rewrite filter.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right, thanks. I changed my rule by including context root like /myapp/js/jquery.js. Now it generated with required absolute url.

Comment: @M.Deinum instead of hard-coding context root in the rewrite rule, is there a way to specify it dynamically.

Comment: I'm able to get context root dynamically by specifying `%{context-path}`. Its working when I use it inside **To** tag but not working inside **From** tag. How to get working inside **From** tag too?